# When i get the album ID for each song it returns duplicates?

Tags: java, android, cursor, mediastore

Code i use to set the **ALBUM ID**:

```
song.setAlbumID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));
```

Now when i log these values in logcat with:

```
Log.d(TAG, "album ids: " + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));
```

**I get this in my logcat:**

```
Song: albumids: [1]
Song: albumids: [3]
Song: albumids: [1]
Song: albumids: [4]
Song: albumids: [5]
Song: albumids: [6]
Song: albumids: [1]
Song: albumids: [1]
Song: albumids: [1]
```

As you can see, multiple songs have the same **ALBUM ID** which gives me a problem when i try to update the **ALBUM ART** because each song with ID 1 will be updated to that **ALBUM ART** i selected.

How to give each Song a **UNIQUE ID** ?

**EDIT**

```
final Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

final String musicsOnly = SONG_IS_MUSIC + "!=0";

    // Querying the Media DATABASE.
    cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, projection1, musicsOnly, null, null);

    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Creating a SONG from the VALUES in each column.
                Song song = new Song(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ID)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_FILEPATH)));

                song.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_TITLE)));
                song.setArtist(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ARTIST)));
                song.setAlbumID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));
                song.setAlbum(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUM)));
                song.setDuration(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_DURATION)));
                song.setYear(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_YEAR)));

                // Using the previously created maps to add the current song GENRE.
                String currentGenreID = songIdToGenreIdMap.get(Long.toString(song.getId()));
                String currentGenreName = genreIdToGenreNameMap.get(currentGenreID);
                song.setGenre(currentGenreName);

                //song.add(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));

                Log.d(TAG, "album id: " + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));

                // Adding the Song to the global array list 'songs'.
                songs.add(song);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

**How i insert new ALBUM ART in Mediastore**

```
 final Uri sArtworkUri = 
 Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
 Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumID);

 ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();  

 ContentValues valuesAlbum = new ContentValues();
   valuesAlbum.put(currentAlbumID, albumID);
   valuesAlbum.put(currentAlbumData, file_path);

   //Update albumArt.
   resolver.delete(albumArtUri, null,null);
   resolver.insert(sArtworkUri, valuesAlbum);
```

Comment: ehm... you are aware that an album can contain more than one ID, right? you may have more luck in getting a album-unique "id", by concatenating artist with albumname

Comment: @Stultuske I dont understand i thought each song had a unique id from MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID. Because i use the album id also to fetch the album art.

Comment: @Stultuske What i noticed is that when an album art is present it returns a UNIQUE ID for that song, but if no ART is found for that song it returns 1?

Comment: is it supposed to return different Id's? You're aware we have no insight in your data, I assume. If you want an easy check: also log the albumname and artistname, and see whether they are different, or debug your code.
How do you decide the id you enter in that column?

Comment: @Stultuske What im trying to achieve is that when i update the album art for a song, not all songs get updated with that album art, because i use the album_id to update it, but because there are multiple ids with same value it will update all songs with that art

Comment: @Stultuske can you check my edit?

Comment: @Stultuske what i dont understand is that why                 song.setAlbumID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID))); returns same ids for different songs?

Comment: you still have only shown how you GET the value, not how you PUT the value in the DB. have you tried to log with more information along?

Comment: @Stultuske i also noticed that each song who has the same ALBUM name has the same ALBUM ID, so now i understand why there are duplicate ids.

Comment: @Stultuske But do you have any idea how i can update an album art from a specific song without changing the album art from another song that has the same id/album name? Check edit how i put it in db

Comment: album art is linked to an album, not a song. so it would be illogical to have different album arts for the same album. are they also from the same artist?

Comment: What you could do, well, try at least, is to change the albumId in the DB for the song for which you want a different image

Comment: @Stultuske yes same artist

Comment: So it's the same album. have you tried resetting the albumId in the DB?

Comment: @Stultuske but how do i generate a new ID ? Can you make a post how to do it ?

Comment: get the highest value (so far), add 1, update the table for that song to have that value as albumId

Comment: @Stultuske replacing the album id wouldn't be a good idea i think, because i have a fragment that displays songs per album, and when i replace a songs album id it would lose the link between the songs in that album right?

Comment: In that case you are stuck with one image for album art for the entire album. Or you should re-write your code that gets the albumart to fetch it based on other parameters

Comment: @Stultuske the method i use to fetch the album art is with Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri,getAlbumID());              Is there another method to fetch album art?

Comment: And then i use Glide library to load the albumArtUri.

Comment: yes, I know. with your current code, all you can have is one piece of album_art per album, and you set it per album. if you want it song by song, you can add a column song_art to your song, add a value for each song you want to have different art. Then, you can get the art values this way:
songArt = getSongArt(); if ( songArt == null ) songArt = getAlbumArt();
and set that, but you'll have to set it per song, not per album

Comment: @Stultuske ok thanks for the help, i will try it.

Comment: @stutulske, your first comment is incorrect. Each album has 1 unique id. Each track has a unique id. The track structure will hold the albumid as a foreign key. The media database is relational.

Answer (score 0):

As none has posted any code :

to get tracks for an album

```
        public Cursor getAlbumTrackIds(Context context, String album_id) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String stralbum_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
    final String track = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String[] columns = {_id};
    final String[] albumid = {album_id};
    String where = stralbum_id + "  = ?";
    return cr.query(uri, columns, where, albumid, track);
}
```

There is no point in updating the media database with albumart as android will take care of this when scanning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what i'm trying to achieve is updating an existing album art in MediaStore and as you can see in my post when a song doesn't have an album art set it will return 1 ( 1 = no album art present for the song), so when i put an image in mediastore it will update all songs that have no album art to that image.

Comment: @Glamericious Blog, it is better to udate the mp3 tag of a track with albumart. Mediastore is a moving target. Even if you update the store, a rescan will most probably undo all your work. Anyway my method gives you all tracks for an album so you are able to loop around the cursor

Comment: I updated title, artist and genres without any problem by getting the values from edittexts and then updating current values with the new values with contentresolver.